# How do I write a Regex pattern to match the following strings?

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have string that could come in several forms

1. “PSM000216556880035450088|TRF”
2. “VNM000216556880035450088|TRF FROM MACK”
3. “NXG000216556880035450088”
4. “Transfer from josh SL000216556880035450088 to jack”
5. “X00000216556880035450088 0098123 TRANSFER 789121”

I need a Regex pattern that could get the string that starts with `PSM`, `VNM`, `NXG`, `SL00` or `X00`.

i.e. in `1`, I need “PSM000216556880035450088”. This string is the reference and it is what I need. It can be found in any position in a sentence and sometimes the reference might not be separated from the other words by a space. Sometimes a special character can be used as a separator. i…e. in `2` “VNM000216556880035450088|TRF FROM MACK”.

I will be using the Regex in my VB.NET code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this with multiline flag?

```
((?:PSM|VNM|NXG|(SL|X)00)\d+)
```